# Do all Windows fonts express extended ASCII in the same way?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, internationalization, iso-8859-1

In my Visual Studio 2012 application, I just wrote the following:

```
_snprintf_s(page[row++], NUM_COLS, _TRUNCATE, " Lat: %-11s (\x0b1 %3.1fm)",
    lat_string, lat_precision_meters);
```

The \xb1 is the escape code for the "+/-" symbol, 177 in extended ASCII, ISO 8859.

I read that this was originally a Windows feature with some other name.

This works for me - it shows the correct symbol next to the precision, in my ***default font***.

My question is: have I just introduced an issue for users who override the default font? Are all Microsoft-provisioned fonts ISO 8859-1 compliant?

Comment: Fonts map Unicode characters. The only problem is with decoding legacy character encodings. This often leads to mojibake since a file will naively be decoded as the system ANSI or OEM codepage. In the West, ANSI is usually codepage 1252, which is a superset of Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) except for differences in the C1 controls range (0x80-0x9F). It happens that ""+/-"  is encoded consistently in the common ANSI codepages, but step over one to 0xb2, and that's "²" in codepage 1252 and "І" in 1251 (Cyrilic).

Comment: Modern applications should use Unicode. If you need bytes, use UTF-8. Otherwise switch to the wide-character API (e.g. `_snwprintf_s`) and use UTF-16LE.

Comment: Windows doesn't use ASCII or any extended ASCII. If applications insist, Windows converts to/from Unicode.